# Removing string quotes from Python string so that after json.dump() quotes won't show in JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a dictionary which contains another dictionary. So within the inner dictionary there is this entry coeff.

```
bias,t1,t2 = data.rpartition(")")
t1,t2,bias = bias.rpartition(",")

resolution,t1,t1 = data.rpartition(")")
t1,t2,resolution = resolution.rpartition("(")
resolution,t1,t2 = resolution.rpartition(",")

coeff = "[ " + str(bias) + ", " + str(resolution) + " ]"
dict = {"a" : "somedata", "coef" : coeff}
```

There are two issues I'm facing here:

***1.*** While using json.dump(), I'm currently getting `"coeffts" : "[ 0, 1 ]",`. I want the output to be `"coeffts" : [ 0.0, 1.0 ],`, without the quotes. I tried using `coeff.replace` and `coeff.strip`, but still the output is the same.

***2.*** I want the values bias and resolution with decimal points. When using *rpartition*, the resulting string may not have decimal point. If it doesn't, I need it to have a decimal point.

> For eg: if what I get from rpartition is 1, I need it to be 1.0. If what I get from rpartition is 0.045, I need it to be same.

Comment: Instead of constructing a string, add your values to a list. Also your dict should use `:` instead of `=`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I typed it in wrong. It was ```:``` and not ```=```. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It's not about whether or not "there are quotes", it's about the **type**. In source code, `"[1, 2, 3]"` is a string and `[1, 2, 3]` is a list. As for your comment on the answer by Paulo44, I will repeat what he said: _The formatting in JSON does not make any difference._ I **strongly recommend** going back and studying more of the basics of Python.

Comment: @MathewThomas I’m still not certain what you mean by _fix it_. Removing the quotes changes the semantics of the JSON, right? What are the types of `bias` and `resolution`?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile So far I have a string variable which I need to encase it between [ and ] with a space between the variable and while dumping into json, I need it to be float, on the same line without quotes. If I add it as float, in the json it'll come on multiple lines. So that is the issue that needs fixing

Comment: @MathewThomas Is the answer by Paulo44 in the right direction? Why do you need it to be on the same line, what is it for? `bias` and `resolution` are strings?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile bias and resolution are strings which are extracted using rpartition. I need them as floating point numbers encased within brackets with a space between the numbers and [ ] and on the same line after json dump.

Comment: @MathewThomas So you need them as a list, no? If they’re strings, why is `str()` being called on them?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Paulo44 answer fixed the floating point issue. It became float, but in the json file, the two values are cascaded.

Comment: @MathewThomas And it fixed the list issue, right?! I want to make sure that we’re clear here.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile If I pass them as a list, the json makes it cascading. I called str because the same values, I had converted to float to assign to another variable. Which is why I called str(). With str I could just concatenate with the brackets and required space. But that created the quotes in json issue, which due to its type.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile it comes as a list. But I want it on the same line, instead of different lines in json. I

Comment: @MathewThomas Right, I understand that, but that doesn’t change the fact that you were apparently calling `str()` on a string, which is what I was asking about.

Comment: @MathewThomas It comes as a list? I know you want it on the same line, and I’m asking **why**. It’s an unusual requirement, is it not?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I agree that its an unusual requirement. And so far I know that cascading doesn't matter when we use json files, but the requirement specifically mentions that and I can't change the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work!

```
coeff = [float(bias),float(resolution)]
```

Also like Klaus D. said change your dictionary to this

```
dict = {"a" : "somedata", "coef" : coeff}
```

Comment: Now the output comes in different lines, I'm getting 

        `"coeffts" : [`
           ` 0.0,`
            `1.0`
       ` ],`

with *coeffts : [* on one line, *bias* on the next, *resolution* on the next and finally *]* on the last.
I want it in the same line, with a space between ```[``` and first value. @Paulo44

Comment: The formatting in JSON does not make any difference.

Comment: @KlausD. can you help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The second issue can be solved using string formatting.

```
coeff = ("[ %2.1f, %2.1f ]" % (float(bias),float(resolution)))
```

Now float values can be put within the string itself or at least printed with floating points.

As for the first issue, the only solution I found is to write to a temp file and then read the file line by line using *readline()*. And then use *replace()* to replace the quotes and  write it to a final file.

```
fin = open(TEMP_JSON_FILE)
fout = open(JSON_FILE, "w+")

line_f = fin.readline()

x1 = '"['
while line_f:
    if x1 in line_f:
        line_f = line_f.replace('\"[', '[').replace(']\"', ']')
        fout.write(line_f)

    else:
        fout.write(line_f)
    line_f = fin.readline()

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

This removes the string quotes from the JSON file. This might not be the most efficient way to do it, but so far this is the best I could find.